# Accuracy of numerical solutions provided by pdetoode

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, discretization

I am interested in solving the following differential equation using pdetoode
(you can find pdetoode [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871)).

```
ClearAll[PowerSubdivide]
  PowerSubdivide[stop_, nfin_] := PowerSubdivide[1, stop, nfin]
   PowerSubdivide[start_, stop_, nfin_] := 
  Exp[Subdivide[Log[start], Log[stop], nfin]]
St = 100;
T0[x_] := Exp[-(x^2/Pi)] - x Erfc[x/Sqrt[Pi]];
domain = {lb, rb} = {0, 35};
tend = 7;
With[{T = T[x, t]}, {eq, ic, 
    bc} = {D[T, t] == D[T, {x, 2}] + St (1 + term) D[T, x], 
    T == T0[x] /. t -> 0, {T == 1 /. x -> lb, T == 0 /. x -> rb}};
  termvalue = D[T, x] /. x -> lb];

points = 1000; difforder = 4; grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
ptoofunc = pdetoode[T[x, t], t, grid, difforder];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;

ode = del@ptoofunc@eq /. term -> ptoofunc@termvalue;
odeic = ptoofunc@ic // del;
odebc = ptoofunc@bc;

sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic, odebc}, 
  T /@ grid, {t, 0, tend}];(*//AbsoluteTiming*)
sol = rebuild[sollst, grid, 2];
```

I would like to vary the parameter `St` from $0.01$ to $100$. However I noticed a bad convergence of the algorithm for large `St`, as for `St=100`, expecially at low values of `t`. I tried to check this convergenze calculating

```
Derivative[1, 0][sol][0, 0](*should be -1*)
St (1 + Derivative[1, 0][sol][0, 0])(*should be 0*)
```

but I got unsatisfactory result for the second value for `St=100`, which should be $0$.

Furthermmore `St (1 + Derivative[1, 0][sol][0, t])` does not tends to its asymptode for `t -> 0` as shown in this figure:

```
numb1 = 20;
data1 = Table[{t , St (1 + Derivative[1, 0][sol][0, t])}, {t, 
   PowerSubdivide[0.000001, tend, numb1]}]
Show[{ListPlot[data1, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
   PlotRange -> All], 
  Plot[2/Pi St ArcTan[Sqrt[(4 t)/Pi]], {t, 0.000001, tend}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}], 
  Plot[St/(1 + St), {t, 0.1, tend}, PlotStyle -> {Red}, 
   ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}]}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Increasing the `points` does not seem to give better results. On the contrary for `St=0.3`, for example, the `t->0` asymptode is reached, even if the data detach from it at very low values of `t`; for `St=0.3` use

```
domain = {lb, rb} = {0, 45};
tend = 110;
```

For example for `St=0.3`, using 50, 100, 500, 1000 and 2000 `points`, I got for

```
St (1 + Derivative[1, 0][sol][0, 0])
```

-0.0105737

-0.0010041

-4.54256*10^-7

-1.4297*10^-8

-4.4702*10^-10

and

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you see, the calculated data are closer to the asymptode for `t->0`

```
2/Pi St ArcTan[Sqrt[(4 t)/Pi]]
```

for smaller times with the increase of the `points`, even if at very small times they start to detach from the asymptode due to some numerical instability.

**Update**
After the suggestions of Alex Trounev, I tray to clarify my point.
Using the algorithm proposed by Alex Trounev for `St=10`, but also using pdetoode, in this case `rb=45` is a good approximation for Infinity:

```
St = 10;
T0[x_] := Exp[-(x^2/Pi)] - x Erfc[x/Sqrt[Pi]];

With[{T = T[x, t]}, {eq, ic, 
    bc} = {D[T, t] == D[T, {x, 2}] + St (1 + term) D[T, x], 
    T == T0[x] /. t -> 0, {T == 1 /. x -> lb, T == 0 /. x -> rb}};
  termvalue = D[T, x] /. x -> lb];


domain = {lb, rb} = {0, 45};
tend = 10; points = 500;
difforder = 2; ugrid = Array[# &, points, domain];

m2 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], ugrid, 
   DifferenceOrder -> difforder]["DifferentiationMatrix"]; m1 = 
 NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], ugrid, 
   DifferenceOrder -> difforder]["DifferentiationMatrix"]; var = 
 Table[u[i], {i, Length[ugrid]}]; vart = 
 Table[u[i][t], {i, Length[ugrid]}]; dvart = 
 Table[u[i]'[t], {i, Length[ugrid]}]; uxx = m2.vart; ux = m1.vart;

eqs = Table[
  dvart[[i]] == uxx[[i]] + St (1 + ux[[1]]) ux[[i]], {i, 2, 
   Length[ugrid] - 1}]; eq12 = {dvart[[1]] == 0, 
  dvart[[Length[ugrid]]] == 0}; ic1 = 
 Table[u[i][0] == T0[ugrid[[i]]], {i, Length[ugrid]}];

sol = NDSolve[{Join[eqs, eq12], ic1}, var, {t, 0, tend}];
```

if I plot

```
 Show[{Plot[St (1 + ux[[1]] /. sol[[1]]), {t, 10^-14, tend}, 
       ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, PlotRange -> All], 
      Plot[2/Pi St ArcTan[Sqrt[(4 t)/Pi]], {t, 10^-14, tend}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}], 
      Plot[St/(1 + St), {t, 0.001, tend}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, 
       ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}]}, Frame -> True, 
     PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> {"t", "St (1+ux[[1]]/.sol[[1]])"}, 
     PlotLabel -> "points=500"]
```

I got different results varying `points`.
[image]
In particular, you see that increasing the `points` I finally reach and stay on the asymptode (see please the knee in the green circle). But after that, the solution departs from the asymptode at lower values of `t`. For `St=100`, I need `points=20000` to reach the asymptode but soon after the solution detaches from the asymptode and I do not manage to stay on it.
[image]
I suspect that the departure from the asymptode at lower values of `t` is due to numerical errors. Is it possible to correct somehow the algorithm so that the solution remains on the asymptode? Maybe without using so many `points`? Or maybe we need to increase the number of grid points along `t`, while it seems that `points` in Trounev's algorithm control just the the number of grid points in `x`?

Any help is really welcome.

Comment: Please be more specific. 1. `St  (1 + Derivative[1, 0][sol][0, 0])(*should be 0*)` evaluates to `-0.00043487`, which doesn't seem to be that bad. What accuracy are you expecting? 2. "St (1 + Derivative[1, 0][sol][0, t]) does not tends to its asymptode  for `t -> 0`" What's the asymptode? And why do you believe the expression should tend to that asymptode?

Comment: Anyway, try `SetOptions[ListInterpolation, InterpolationOrder -> difforder]` before executing that `rebuild[...]` line.

Comment: No substantial change with `SetOptions`.

Comment: With `SetOptions`, `St  (1 + Derivative[1, 0][sol][0, 0])(*should be 0*)` becomes `-1.3586*10^-6` for your setting. And, please answer the questions in my first comment.

Comment: Thanks @xzczd, I am just trying to replicate results found in an article where the two aymptodes are demonstrated.

Comment: Is the parameter `St=100` used in that article? And, you haven't answered the other questions in my first comment so far.

Comment: Thank you @xzczd. `St=100` is not used, max `St` used is 11, I have to confess. `St (1 + Derivative[1, 0][sol][0, t])` should tend to the asymptode for `t->0`.  Probably is a matter of visualization in a log-log plot, as pointed out by Alex Trounev. I aspected the calculate points to be closer to the asymptode for t->0 (this is what I meant for greater accuracy, very bad definition though).

Comment: Just to add more details, `xb` is infinite, I adopted a finite value for the numerical computation. Acutally, the finite value of `xb`, ment to indicate infinite, should change for any `St`, in particular it has to increase with the decrease of `St`.

Answer (score 3):

As we know `pdetoode` can be used to discretize PDE, and therefore it can be replaced with any other FDM algorithm, for example

```
St = 100;
T0[x_] := Exp[-(x^2/Pi)] - x Erfc[x/Sqrt[Pi]];

With[{T = T[x, t]}, {eq, ic, 
    bc} = {D[T, t] == D[T, {x, 2}] + St (1 + term) D[T, x], 
    T == T0[x] /. t -> 0, {T == 1 /. x -> lb, T == 0 /. x -> rb}};
  termvalue = D[T, x] /. x -> lb];


domain = {lb, rb} = {0, 35};
tend = 7; points = 4000; difforder = 2; ugrid = 
 Array[# &, points, domain];

m2 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], ugrid, 
   DifferenceOrder -> difforder]["DifferentiationMatrix"]; m1 = 
 NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], ugrid, 
   DifferenceOrder -> difforder]["DifferentiationMatrix"]; var = 
 Table[u[i], {i, Length[ugrid]}]; vart = 
 Table[u[i][t], {i, Length[ugrid]}]; dvart = 
 Table[u[i]'[t], {i, Length[ugrid]}]; uxx = m2 . vart; ux = m1 . vart;

eqs = Table[
  dvart[[i]] == uxx[[i]] + St (1 + ux[[1]]) ux[[i]], {i, 2, 
   Length[ugrid] - 1}]; eq12 = {dvart[[1]] == 0, 
  dvart[[Length[ugrid]]] == 0}; ic1 = 
 Table[u[i][0] == T0[ugrid[[i]]], {i, Length[ugrid]}];

sol = NDSolve[{Join[eqs, eq12], ic1}, var, {t, 0, tend}];
```

If we plot in log-log coordinate function `St (1+ux[[1]]/.sol[[1]])` together with asymptotic solution, then we have

```
Show[{Plot[St (1 + ux[[1]] /. sol[[1]]), {t, 10^-14, tend}, 
   ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, PlotRange -> All], 
  Plot[2/Pi St ArcTan[Sqrt[(4 t)/Pi]], {t, 10^-14, tend}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}], 
  Plot[St/(1 + St), {t, 0.1, tend}, PlotStyle -> {Red}, 
   ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}]}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure 1]

It looks like a large discrepancies with asymptotic solution, but this is kind of illusion due to log-log coordinates. If we plot solution in unscaled coordinates then it looks different

```
Show[Plot[St (1 + ux[[1]] /. sol[[1]]), {t, 0, .01}, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[2/Pi St ArcTan[Sqrt[(4 t)/Pi]], {t, 0, .01}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, PlotRange -> {0, St/(1 + St)}], 
 Plot[St/(1 + St), {t, 0, .01}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}], 
 Frame -> True]

Show[Plot[St (1 + ux[[1]] /. sol[[1]]), {t, 0, tend}, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[2/Pi St ArcTan[Sqrt[(4 t)/Pi]], {t, 0, .01}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, PlotRange -> {0, St/(1 + St)}], 
 Plot[St/(1 + St), {t, 0, tend}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}], 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: Figure 2]
[image: Figure 3]

Please note that

```
ux[[1]] /. sol[[1]] /. t -> 0

(*-1.*)
```

and

```
St (1 + ux[[1]] /. sol[[1]] /. t -> 0)

(*Out[]= 6.79265*10^-6 *)
```

Update 1. To plot solution at a given `t={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}`  we use

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[Transpose[{ugrid, vart /. sol[[1]]}], {t, 0, 7, 1}], 
 PlotLegends -> Range[0, 7], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure 4]

In a small scale it looks like

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[Transpose[{ugrid, vart /. sol[[1]]}], {t, 0, 7, 1}], 
 PlotLegends -> Range[0, 7]]
```

[image: Figure 5]

Comment: Is it possible to plot the solution, `T`, as function of `x` for a given value of `t`, I have not really understood the structue of the solution, `sol`, it looks like an array of interpolating functions at `t=0`.

Comment: @umby See Update 1 to my answer.

Comment: @AlexTrunev, it seems that the variable `points = 4000` controls only the grid spacing along `x`. Is it possible to control also the grid spacing along `t` or `NDSolve` takes care automatically of it? Probably increasing the numbers of points along `t` will produce a lower discrepancy of `St (1 + ux[[1]] /. sol[[1]]` with respect to the asymptote for `t->0`. Many thanks, also for what you have done so far.